# Intellisense not working on multiple files

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I am currently developing some JS/ES projects with vscode and a bunch of extensions.
But sadly, the intellisense feature of VSCode does not work as intended.

Please see the repo https://github.com/svennergr/intellisense-test as an example setup of my project.
The exact point I am talking about is the intellisense or type declaration of the "component" in Main.js. VSCode shows the type "Component" just as any:

[image: Component as any]

Only when I import the Component and its typedef to the Main.js file, the intellisense definition works as intended:

[image: Component with def]

But I don't want this import here, since I don't use it any further.
Is there a way to configure VSCode's intellisense to also get typedefs from other project files?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, that there definetly needs to be any kind of import. Instead of importing the Component to the whole file, it can only be imported into the typedef like the following:

```
   * @param {import('./Component').default} [component] The component to assign.
```